# Explanation of WCF application life cycle in IIS 6 hosting environment

Tags: iis, wcf, lifecycle

Hi all and thanks for reading,

I have a delay issue where my application takes a long time to start up when first called after an determinate period since the last call. The web application is a WCF service and we are talking about a delay of ~18seconds before the actual processing starts. Now, I believe I know how to reduce this delay so that is not my question (it's more a stackoverflow deal anyway)

**My question is**, Can anyone explain to me why is it that despite me disabling worker process shutdown, and worker process recycling the application still 'winds down' after a indeterminate period of time of inactivity?

To understand this I need to know more about the innerworkings of WCF services hosted in IIS. I fully expect there to be a straight forward answer to this.

Thank you v. much for any help you may offer,
DC

Comment: Can you please share what caused the issue you described here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is unchecked on the Recycling and Performance tab of the worker process, IIS should not be terminating the processes.  Are there any event log entries that correspond to the time the process "winds down"?  It sounds to me like the WCF app is potentially crashing out.  WCF doesn't log exceptions to the event log like a standard .NET app so if you aren't writing your own logs, you may want to turn on [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx) to see if perhaps thats the issue.

The quick ugly solution to your problem in the meantime may be to create some sort of cheap test or read only transaction in your WCF service and just configure a monitoring app or script to poll it every X seconds to keep the worker process alive with the code pre-JIT'd.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was unrelated to WCF, and the fault lay with nHibernate sorting out it's mappings.  I solved it by compiling the nHibernate mapping files so nHibernate didnt have to.